# Is it possible to use PrimeFaces dataTable in IceFaces environment?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, icefaces

I have an application using IceFaces 3.3 (non-EE version) for user interface. I would like to replace some of the pages to PrimeFaces.

As a trivial case, I created a new page with only HTML and PrimeFaces tags on it. There is a sortable and filterable lazy dataTable on the page and nothing else. The table first loads fine but when I initiate a sorting or filtering operation, the entire table disappears.

When I inspect the page, I see IcePush is operating and the IceFaces Bridge is loaded. In case of the above mentioned partial page reload, in the response XML, the dataTable appears within delete tags however, it should be present within update tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding org.icefaces.subtreeDiff=false to web.xml solves the problem.